# Simple password with uitextfield in swift

Tags: ios, swift, passwords, uitextfield

I am trying to make a login page that will allow someone to type in a simple 6 digit numerical passcode. The log in page will come already set with the password of "719403" and the user can't change it. If the passcode is correct it will segue to a different viewcontroller, but if the password is wrong then nothing will happen.

Comment: Do you already have a text field set up with appropriate delegate methods?

Comment: Simply implement `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and check the value in the text field, returning `true` or `false` as required.

Comment: @AdamZarn I only have the UItextfield set up on the storyboard

Comment: then add a login button and navigate it to next screen according to condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an @IBOutlet of your UITextField and set your viewController to be a delegate of your text field in viewDidLoad.

```
self.textField.delegate = self
```

Then when you want to initiate the segue, check to see if your textField value equals "719403":

```
if self.textField.text == "719403" {
//perform segue
}
```

Comment: I am having an error with setting self.textfield.delegate to self. I added the outlet and called the textField "textField" but it have an error under the second self

Comment: Do i have to added in a delegate to my class?

Comment: Right, change to class ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: Check my answer down below

Answer (score 0):

You can implement NSNotification with UITextFieldTextDidChange notification name.
Put this code in viewWillAppear

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textFieldChanged(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidChange, object: nil)
```

And implement this function as well

```
func textFieldChanged(_ info:Notification) {

       if self.textField.text == "719403" {
          //perform segue
       }
}
```

Comment: Check my answer down below

Comment: The one you implemented requires a button for the action. In my solution, as soon as the textField matches the value it goes to the next controller.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem.

You need to create an outlet for the Uitextfield and then make a "Login" button. Make the login button an action and have it perform this action

```
if self.textField.text == "719403" {
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: nil)
}
```